# Non-Dimensionaliztion of coupled equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm going over some review for a project I'm doing over the summer and ran into a problem of non-Nondimensionalization. I have not done it in a while and am struggling on how to approach this problem. All that it's asking is for me to non-dimensionlize this into the relevant number of parameters and show there are either two or zero positive steady states. 
both graphically and analytically. I deleted an old post because there was a lot of information missing on my end

There are two equations

$\frac{dx}{dt}=k_1\frac{y^2}{K+y^2}-k_2x$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=h_1\frac{x^2}{H+x^2}-h_2y$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you means something like "if $x$ is measured in meters and $t$ in seconds, then $k_1$ has unit or dimension $[m/s]$ and $k_2$ is measured in $[Hz]=[1/s]$"?

Comment: the only thing not being told is the fact that k1,k2,K,H,h1,h2 are all positive constants

Comment: wouldn't I need to have some sort of $u=x....v=x... and \tau =t....$

Answer (score 0):

At stationary points different from zero,
$$
x=\frac{ky^2}{K+y^2},\qquad y=\frac{hx^2}{H+x^2}=\frac{hk^2y^4}{H(K+y^2)^2+k^2y^4},
$$
$k=k_1/k_2$, $h=h_1/h_2$, which can be transformed into a degree $4$ polynomial in $y$.